# SSL pass through proxy(not mitm)

Tags: proxy, https

How to start a ssl passthrough proxy? I need to start proxy that will not decrypt https data(I don't want to perform mitm). Instead of this it must just send it to requested server and return response. So the scheme: client asks my dns server for domain --> dns returns ip of proxy --> client sends request to proxy(which listens on 443 port) as for requested site --> proxy returns the response.

I tried some proxy scripts solutions. But they were working only when I set proxy for request, for example,

```
curl --proxy ip:443 https://google.com
```

When i navigate to  https://google.com from the browser and dns server returns ip of proxy, the proxy doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason why any proxy shouldn't do what you want to do. The client will open a connection to the proxy, use the `CONNECT` command, and will then have a transparent connection to the desired server. The proxy will not be able to do mitm, as that is the point of SSL. It isn't even necessary for the client to do the DNS lookup, the proxy can do that, too.

So your statement "the proxy doesn't work" is the consequence of "you configured something wrong". Unfortunately, you didn't give any details.